# JBoss EAP 7 - erroneous trace on Injected Resources

Tags: web-services, dependency-injection, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I have run into an issue that I thought I might see if anyone knows the answer to.  It's not too big a problem as the resources are actually being injected - however the console is showing and informational warning that the resources failed to resolve.

This problem doesn't occur in EAP 5.1.2.  I was just curious if anyone else has run into the problem and possibly I'm not doing things properly in EAP 7 and thus there's a workaround.

Background:

1. EJB Web Service packaged in a EAR.  EAR has no application.xml or jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Note:  though I did try adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml just to see if it helped.

2. Stateless EJB is a webservice

**Here's a snippet from the ejb-jar.xml file:**

```
        <env-entry>
            <description>Variable to distinguish between prod, uat and qa environments</description>
            <env-entry-name>net.mycompany.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyWSService.isUAT</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>false</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>

        <env-entry>
            <description>Variable to distinguish between prod, uat and qa environments</description>
            <env-entry-name>isQA</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>false</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
```

As you can see, I tried it both ways, e.g. with full package and class name in env-entry-name as well as just the plain old env entries name

**Here's the Web Service code snippet:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Stateless
@Local(IMyWSService.class)
@WebService
public class MyWSService implements IMyWSService {

    @Resource(name = "isUAT")
    private boolean isUAT;
    @Resource
    private boolean isQA;

    @WebMethod
    @ResponseWrapper(localName="doSomethingResponse", className="Response", targetNamespace="http://model.mysubpackage.mypackage.net")
    public Response doSomething
    (@WebParam(name="param1", mode=Mode.IN) String param1
    , @WebParam(name="param2", mode=Mode.IN) String param2
    , @WebParam(name="param3", mode=Mode.IN) String param3) {

    //more and more code
    .
    .
    .
    //pertinent method
    initAndSetEnvEntrieVars();
    .
    .
    .
    //the method which actually utilizes the environment variables
    private void initAndSetEnvEntrieVars() {
    //setup env-entry related vars
            if(isUAT){
                System.out.println("We're in UAT");

            }else if(isQA){
                System.out.println("We're in QA");
            }
    }
```

**Note:** and again, the values are actually being injected and theres about 15 that I removed from code for brevity.

**Heres the output in JBoss console**

```
12:43:34,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDS0004: Found MyUseful.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called MyUseful.ear.dodeploy
12:43:34,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "MyUseful.ear" (runtime-name: "MyUseful.ear")
12:43:34,968 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "MyUsefulService.jar")
12:43:35,017 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment MyUseful.ear
12:43:35,030 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment MyUsefulService.jar
12:43:35,032 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'MyWSService' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "MyUsefulService.jar" of deployment "MyUseful.ear"' are as follows:

java:global/MyUseful/MyUsefulService/MyWSService!net.mycompany.mypackage.mysubpackage.IMyWSService 
java:app/MyUsefulService/MyWSService!net.mycompany.mypackage.mysubpackage.IMyWSService 
java:module/MyWSService!net.mycompany.mypackage.mysubpackage.IMyWSService 

12:43:35,034 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: MyUseful.ear
12:43:35,036 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment MyUseful.ear
12:43:35,056 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:43:35,057 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:43:35,057 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=MyWSService
 address=http://localhost:8080/MyUsefulService/MyWSService
 implementor=net.mycompany.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyWSService
 serviceName={http://model.mysubpackage.mypackage.net/}MyWSServiceService
 portName={http://model.mysubpackage.mypackage.net/}MyWSServicePort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
12:43:35,058 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:43:35,058 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:43:35,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
12:43:35,080 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-7) Creating Service {http://model.mysubpackage.mypackage.net/}MyWSServiceService from class net.mycompany.mypackage.mysubpackage..MyWSService
12:43:35,144 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-7) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/MyUsefulService/MyWSService
12:43:35,146 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector] (MSC service thread 1-7) failed to resolve resource isUAT
12:43:35,147 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector] (MSC service thread 1-7) failed to resolve resource isQA
12:43:35,183 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS024074: WSDL published to: file:/C:/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/data/wsdl/MyUseful.ear/MyUsefulService.jar/MyWSServiceService.wsdl
12:43:35,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWS0003: Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."MyUseful.ear"."MyUsefulService.jar".MyWSService
12:43:35,378 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /MyUsefulService
12:43:35,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MyUseful.ear" (runtime-name : "MyUseful.ear")
```

**Again**, this is more of just a nuisance, but I felt I'd run it by all of you just in case someone else gets stuck researching it for hours.

**Update**: sorry I didnt realize the difference between StackExchange and StackOverFlow - had always wondered why the different names... but too busy to find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after getting some help/advice from the good guys, e.g. Alessio Soldano and jaikiran pai in the JBoss forums Alessio basically said:
"Hi,
I'd need to go and check the code to confirm, but I think what's happening there is that the WS layer basically goes through different mechanism for having the values there injected. First it tries letting Apache CXF layer resolve the values, if that fails (with the log shown here) it uses the internal JBoss mechanism, which is what is actually getting the values from the ejb-jar.xml descriptor here."

and...

"simply ignore that message in the log and you're done. It's basically an internal thing, the log comes from apache cxf so there's not much we can do in this case to avoid it.
The thread you linked is related to a slightly different scenario which was caused by a bug (well, a missing feature at that time), but that's solved."

The forum post is:
[JBoss EAP 7 - erroneous trace on Injected Resources](https://developer.jboss.org/message/965900#965900)

If anyone ever wants to follow up on it further - looks like we're just stuck with it for now